# Backward compatible billing code for android

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility, billing

When setting up the billing service on an android app, I have code:

```
     IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener listener = new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
             if (!result.isSuccess()) { 
                 String errorMsg = result.getMessage();
```

It runs fine on devices with newish versions of android, but when I run it on a device with the old Market app version 2.3.4, I get the error message:

```
 Billing service unavailable on device. (response: 3:Billing Unavailable)
```

I would very much like not to exclude users who have older versions of android and are still using the market app, rather than google play. It is not a practical solution to ask them all update the software version.

So **what do I need to do to make my billing code backward compatible?**
I'd like my app to work with android version 2.2 (and later).

Thanks

Comment: Android version is only tangentially related to Market/Google Play Store version. Are you asking on how to support people who specifically downgrade their version of Google Play Store/Google Services from the auto-updated versions provided by Google to all 2.2+ devices?

Comment: I would like the billing to work for as many users as possible. For example I have one user who is using android version 2.3.3, with market version 2.3.4.
Currently on his phone, the billing doesn't work, the error message is shown above. 
What do I need to do to my code to get it to work on his phone?
An alternative, which I don't want, is to exclude many android users and say only those with version X of some android software on their phone will be able to use our app.

Comment: check this link, it may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133586/in-app-billing-v3-support

Comment: Thanks Maulik,
that link is helpful.

Comment: @pnelnik i m facing same problem please tell me the solution to solve this problem

Comment: itechDroid, the link from Maulik above is the best answer I could find.